# How we can send object by using Firebase cloud messaging for push notification in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How we can send objects in  firebase cloud messaging in android.
I want to send in message other than Text like image ,text,etc in android through 
 firebase cloud messaging for push notification.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the usual use-case for Push Notifications. For FCM, it is strongly advised not to send over images, primarily because of the payload size limit - 2KB for `notification`, 4KB for `data`.

I suggest using [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) for storing the images, then downloading it in the device when needed, maybe even just sending the download URL in the push notification instead as a workaround.